# What is the average counts of an HTTP request/response header?

Tags: http

I want to put those headers in a fixed size array(fast path), if the header count exceed the size of array then put it in a list(slow path), so it is meaningful for me to know the average counts of an HTTP request/response header. Thanks advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good question, because it kinda falls under 'please do my work for me', or perhaps 'find me the statistics'. It's not really a strict programming question. I would recommend you start with a bunch of research yourself first.

Comment: I did searched on Google, I can only get the average size of http headers(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358109/what-is-the-average-size-of-an-http-request-response-header/5358276), which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: I found this post(https://www.vanimpe.eu/2014/09/01/analyze-http-headers-part-2/), which covered HTTP response headers. And it says "Over 40% of the HTTP headers are Connection, Date, Content-Type and Server", so maybe 16 is a reasonable answer for response header

Comment: Are you strictly looking for a number of headers? For browsers? If so, why not set something up that measures the actual traffic you're doing yourself.

Comment: Because this result could be changed based on the type of browsers and the web app you are accessing, so I can not get those statistics on my own. Anyway, after briefly checking my browsers  and some regular websites, I decided to use 16 for both request and response header. Thanks very much.